# Development version of docker-compose.yml in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

In my Spring Boot app, I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that is used Dockerizing my app with `Dockerfile`. On the other hand, for the local development, other developers would also need a `docker-compose.yml` file for creating MySQL on a local Docker environment.

For this kind of general situations, what is the proper way to provide the configuration for local development besides Dockerizing? I look but there seems to be no `docker-compose-dev.yml` file usage as far as I see. So, what should I do? Where keep my compose config? I think I can use any whatever file name but in this case should it be a differennt location than the default one?

Answer (score 0):

Name the developer-oriented file `docker-compose.override.yml`.  If this file is present, Compose will use its settings to augment and override the settings in the main `docker-compose.yml`.  See [Multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files) in the Docker documentation for more details.

Typically if you have this file, you'll do pre-production testing and deployment using only the main `docker-compose.yml` file but not the override file.  This works better if the settings in the override file are purely additive.

You might have a production-oriented Compose file like, for example,

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: registry.example.com/app:${APP_TAG:-latest}
    environment: [MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_DATABASE MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD]
```

where most of the interesting settings are injected from host environment variables, and expecting to interface with an external database.  In development, though, you might want to build this image from source and install a database as part of the setup

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      ET: cetera
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    volumes: ['mysql:/var/lib/mysql/data']
    environment: {...}
volumes:
  mysql:
```

The settings from the two files are combined, so if you

```bash
APP_TAG=20221109 docker-compose build
```

you'll wind up with an image name `registry.example.com/app:20221109`, for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these wonderful explanations, voted up (but cannot I need 4 point). From the documentation, I see that >>>

Comment: **1.** whenever I run `docker-compose up`, only `docker-compose.override.yml` is executed if both of them are present. Right?

Comment: **2.** And when I need to execute production one(s), but not `docker-compose.override.yml`, then I should use `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d` or `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d`. Right?

Comment: Any confirmation please?

Comment: Just don't copy the override file to your production environment.